# pandas rows to columns with additional columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Assuming that I have the below dataframe df:

```
type  cat  val
a     x      3
a     x1     1
a     x2     3.5
b     x3     7
b     x4     2
c     x1     8
```

Now I am trying to obtain something like below:

```
type  cat1    val1    cat2   val2   cat3   val3   cat4   val4
a     x        3      x2     3.5     x2     7     nan    nan
b     x3       7      nan    nan     nan    nan   x4     2
c     x1       8      nan    nan     nan    nan   nan    nan
```

So basically I have created 04 new columns base on the unique values of 'cat', and then assign 'val' into the cells accordingly, and the new table is indexed by 'type'.

Would this be something that pandas pivot table would help?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `pd.pivot_table()`:

```
# make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'type' : ['a']*3 + ['b']*2 + ['c'],
                   'cat' : ['x', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x1'],
                   'val' : [3, 1, 3.5, 7, 2, 8]})

# pivot
df.pivot_table(index = 'type',
               columns = 'cat',
               values = 'val')
```

[image: pivot]

It doesn't have the columns like you have them but it does reduce the dimensions and the number of `NaN`s.

Hope this helps!